# Clusterize item set with items as vectors of features

Tags: clustering, data, k-means

I have to clusterize this dataset in which I have houses and water consumption in this form:
$$
House1 = (x_{1},x_{2}... x_{n});\\
House2 = (y_{1},y_{2}... y_{n});\\
House3 = (z_{1},z_{2}... z_{n});\\
$$
where $x_{i}$ is the daily consumption in liters while  $n$ is a fixed parameter (length of dataset).

I need to cluster these houses in k clusters based on their water consumption.

My question is: how can I handle data expressed in this form to feed in the clustering algorithm?
Maybe I will have to agglomerate each vector in some real value?

Answer (score 0):

1.you just have to represent those  features as numeric in a vector
eg:[2,4,8,10]

2.Its a good  practise to normalize vector i just took sum of elements and divide by each element by that sum of elements  =[0.06666666666666667,0.13333333333333333,0.2,0.26666666666666666,0.3333333333333333]
normalize the values in that vector to be between 0 -1

3.feed the vectors into clustering algorithm (you can try with kmeans)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to treat each house as a time series, and then cluster the time series. Some approaches have adapted k-means to times series data, see the R package [kml](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kml/index.html).

I also like using mixture models though for similar problems, as the underlying time series can be quite flexible. Here I have an example using [pytorch](https://github.com/apwheele/Blog_Code/blob/master/Using%20Pytorch%20for%20group%20based%20trajectory%20models.ipynb), and the R package [flexmix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/index.html) is quite good as well.

flexmix also extends to data if it has unequal time stamps. You pass the data in long format and give it a grouping factor. See [here](https://andrewpwheeler.com/2021/03/05/simulating-group-based-trajectories-in-r/) for an example.

A final example I have see is [estimate various time series characteristics](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10618-005-0039-x) for each individual series (e.g. ARIMA), and then cluster those characteristics. So each house is turned into a single row in that scenario.